# editing/viewing a Microsoft Outlook NK2 name cache file

Tags: outlook

I am trying to find some code which shows how one might open an Outlook NK2 names cache file.  I did some searching and I have seen several people say that it's not possible, but then I find links to some freeware that can do just this so I know its possible.  I would use the freeware applications, but would rather do it in my own code, and it easier to get an approval from management if I use my own code within my organization rather then a freeware/shareware application.  I'm trying to write the code in VB, but I would like to find a example in any language if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Redemption has some [Nk2 examples](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdonicknames.htm), although you may have to pay for a commercial license.

There is also a project on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/debunk2/) that has a lot of good stuff in it to get you started.